# validate a date in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just want to validate a given input from the user

```
Declare @UserInput NVARCHAR(20)
set @UserInput = '26/07/2013'
select ISDATE(@UserInput)
```

This will return false as the date is in australian format, even though the date is valid

I can change the last line to the folowing

```
select isdate(CONVERT(datetime, @UserInput, 103))
```

and it works.  But if the @Userinput was rubbish (ie:- 'hello'), then the last statement would fail.  How can I have something, where no matter what the user enters, it validates it to an australian date (dd/mm/yyyy)?

Thanks

Comment: I think such validations should take place in a calling application, not in query text.

Comment: Bear in mind that no amount of validation like this can save you from *ambiguous* dates - if you've received just `04/09/2013`, you've got no way of knowing whether the user *intended* a day in April or September.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[SET DATEFORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)** to specify the format you are expecting the date to be entered in:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

Declare @UserInput NVARCHAR(20)
set @UserInput = '26/07/2013'
select ISDATE(@UserInput)
```

I would be inclined to perform such validations prior to the input reaching SQL-Server, and ensuring that any date variables are dates.

Comment: by using set DateFormat does it change the dateformat of the sql install? or is it only valid for the current script?

Comment: @user2206329 Taken from the linked aticle - `It does not affect the display of date data type values that are stored in the database or the storage format`

Comment: @user2206329, from the documentation for the [SET statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) - "The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements that change the current session handling of specific information."  So the current session is the scope.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2012 and above, you could use [TRY_CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) instead:

`select isdate(TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @UserInput, 103))`

Comment: Why the ISDATE check ... just check against TRY_CONVERT returning NULL?

Comment: @ta.speot.is No other reason than the OP originally used `IsDate()` so I am assuming they want a true/false outcome. But yes, they could just check against `Try_Convert`.