# how to fetch all columns with incorrect date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in which all columns are of type `TEXT`. There is a field called `PurchaseDate` which contains a date value (but its stored in text format as mentioned before).

```
Create Table Orders (
    OrderID TEXT,
    OrderDate TEXT,
    ShippingAddr TEXT
)
```

OrderDate has data (i.e. date) of the pattern 'dd-mm-yyyy'.

My goal is to determine if the particular field has data in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format.

I know that I have to query those records which fail to match this pattern in order to determine whether the data stored in the field is valid for consumption.

But how to write the query for this?

Edit:

The only idea I've got so far is a kind of MS Sql server solution. However even that doesn't  provide a way to get a list of records. You put something like the following in the select list:

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderDate, 101), ... From ... ;
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If ever your date is 01-01-2013, how would you determine if its 'dd-mm-yyyy' or 'mm-dd-yyyy'?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How can you distinguish between '06-07-2013 and 07-06-2013' for the 6th of July and 7th June seeing as both are valid?

Comment: Could anyone tell me how to use the regexp clause in the query...

Comment: what do you mean  by _incorrect date?_ 31/2/2012 is this incorrect ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi that could be a case...Another case, suppose your locale is US then the above date is incorrect since a month cannot be 31, ever.

Answer (score 1):

To find records where the date is known to be incorrect, search for dates where the supposed month (fourth and fifth characters) is larger than twelve:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE substr(OrderDate, 4, 2) > '12'
```

This does not help for dates that could be correct in either format, i.e., where both day and month values are at most twelve.

Answer (score 0):

1) As you suggested yourself you can try regexp:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx
But the regexp support in T-SQL seems pretty limited to me.

2) You can check this one and see if the accepted answer helps you.
[validate a date in t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094315/validate-a-date-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are filtering data, so I will use `WHERE` clauses.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DATE(SUBSTR(OrderDate, 7)||SUBSTR(OrderDate, 3, 4)||SUBSTR(OrderDate, 1, 2)) IS NULL;
```

This will select all rows where `OrderDate` is not valid `DD-MM-YYYY`.